# Magento 2 How to Delete permanently Image folder from pub\media\catalog\product\cache?

Tags: magento2, media, media-images

Actually, I try to manually delete the pub\media\catalog\product\cache folder but when I go to the Product Page in the Admin Panel the pub\media\catalog\product\cache folder was Regenerated how to stop automatically regenerating folder because I need is to permanently delete the media folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete in database

When you delete pub/media, it is will regenerated.

so please check in database.